# PHP : I have String want to capitalize some letters in it using arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string

the string is = "Hello I am an awesome developer, I love PHP "
and I want the result "HEllO I am an awEsOme dEvElOper, I lOvE PHP " so how should I write the code and now will show you my code

```
$str= "Hello I am an awesome developer, I love PHP";

echo $str . "<br>";
$arr = str_split($str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
for($i=0 ; $i< count($arr);$i++){
   if ( $arr[$i] == 'e' ){
    $arr[$i] = str_replace('e','E',$arr);

   }
   echo "<li>" . $arr[$i] . "</li>";
   }
```

Comment: Which letters do you want to capitalise, what is your methodology?

Comment: Do you want to capitalise only the vowels and existing capitals?

Comment: You've shown some code, that's a good start. Now you need to show us what result this code gives, and what result you hoped it would give.

Comment: Also, hint: https://www.php.net/strtoupper

Answer (score 1):

I created an function for capitalize random letters:

```php
<?php //php 7.2.24

function mocker($text) {
    $firstpass = str_split($text);
    $outstring = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $outstring[$i] = strtoupper($firstpass[$i]);
        }
        elseif (ctype_upper($outstring[$i-1])) {

            if (mt_rand(0,3) >= 2) {
                $outstring[$i] = strtoupper($firstpass[$i]);
            }
            else {
                $outstring[$i] = strtolower($firstpass[$i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (mt_rand(0,3) >= 2) {
                $outstring[$i] = strtolower($firstpass[$i]);
            }
            else {
                $outstring[$i] = strtoupper($firstpass[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $outstring;
}
```

Usage: `echo mocker("Hello I am an awesome developer, I love PHP");`

Result: `HElLO i AM An awEsOME dEVelopEr, i LovE PhP`

I did it randomly as I don't understand exactly what it will upper or lower.
You can change values if you want. So you can get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking the problem.

You have a list of letters to capitalise, `e` or `o` and you do not wish to change anything else.

Looks like a perfect case for [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = "Hello I am an awesome developer, I love PHP";
$find = array('e','o');
$replace = array('E','O');
$result = str_replace($find,$replace,$str);
```

`$result` will now be `"HEllO I am an awEsOmE dEvElOpEr, I lOvE PHP"`

Comment: to not have to manually set `$replace` one could use: `$replace = array_flip(array_change_key_case(array_flip($find), CASE_UPPER));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to easily choose the letters you wish to capitalize, I propose devising a function:

```php
function capitalizeLetters(string $string, array $letters): string
{
    $replacements = array_combine($letters, array_map('strtoupper', $letters));
    return strtr($string, $replacements);
}
```

With this, you can simply call it like so:

```php
$str = "Hello I am an awesome developer, I love PHP";
capitalizeLetters($str, ['e', 'o']);
```

and it will result in what you want.

How it works:

- `strtr` replaces all the occurrences based on the replacement array it receives.
- Replacements are created through `array_combine`, which takes our letters as keys and their capitalized versions as values. This results in an array like this:

```php
[
    'e' => 'E',
    'o' => 'O',
]
```

- The capitalization for the values is done through `array_map`, which applies the `strtoupper` function to all the elements.

Comment: Live test available in [this fiddle](https://3v4l.org/9mGHf).